# I am attempting to add a whitespace to the middle of char array. Unsure of how to move it properly

Tags: c++, arrays, char, whitespace

I am checking an array for a sentence end and then making sure there is a space after sentence end. I am attempting to move all the array 1 to the right to make room for the whitespace. `userPara[]` is just a user entered char array. I CANNOT use strings but can use string class

```
void add_whitespace(char userPara[])
{
    int len = strlen(userPara);
    int newlen = len + 1;
    char temp1;
    char temp2;
    char whitespace = ' ';
    for (int i = 0; i < newlen; i++) {
        if (userPara[i-1] == '.' || userPara[i-1] == '?' || userPara[i-1] == 
            '!' && userPara[i] != ' ') {
            temp1 = userPara[i];
            userPara[i] = whitespace;
            for (int j = i; j < newlen; j++) {
                temp2 = userPara[j+1];
                userPara[j+1] = temp1;
                temp1 = userPara[j+2];
                userPara[j+2] = temp2;
                cout << userPara << endl; //This is for testing
            }
         }
     }
}
```

it seems to be just moving the the first [j+1] element to the right until that element is out of the string

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187889/discussion-on-question-by-dylan-i-am-attempting-to-add-a-whitespace-to-the-middl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in your inner `for` you shift to right two elements of `userPara`, you should increment the counter by 2 (`j+=2` not `j++`).
One example for you purpose could be the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if(userPara [i] == '.')
    {
        temp1 = userPara [i];
        userPara [i] = ' ';
         for (int j = i+1; j < n; j+=2)
         {
            temp2 = userPara [j];
            userPara [j] = temp1;
            temp1 = userPara [j+1];
            userPara [j+1] = temp2;
         }
    break;    
    }

}
```

As discussed in the comments please note that this approach may have issues regarding this blindly increasing of the array.